# Jira create_issue API is throwing exception whenever there us the keyword column_name in description field. Why does this occur and how to fix this?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

```
Auth_jira.create_issue(json_issue['fields'])
```

The above is jira API call.
It is throwing exception whenever there is the keyword `column_name` in description field of JSON.

Want create issue to work. Want to know if anyone faced same issue and what is the cause of this occurring too.